# Django does not match urls

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I've been working on a django web app (using Django 1.3), a web catalogue of products, and it was working fine until I was asked to add a custom admin site. I'm fully aware of the Django admin site, but the client is very old-fashioned, and is tech-ignorant so I have to make a "for dummies" version admin site. The root urlconf:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from store.models import Category

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^^$', TemplateView.as_view(
            template_name='homepage.html',
            get_context_data=lambda: {
                'crumb': 'home',
                'category_list':Category.objects.all()
                }
            ), 
        name='home'),
    url(r'^favicon\.ico$', 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to', {'url': '/static/img/favicon.ico'}),
    url(r'^store/', include('store.urls', app_name='store', namespace='store')),
)
```

And the urlconf for the store app:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *


from store import views


urlpatterns = patterns ('',
    url(r'^category/$', views.get_brands, name='get_brands'),
    url(r'^(\w+)/$', views.GalleryView.as_view(), name='gallery'),
    url(r'^(\w+)/(\w+)/$', views.GalleryView.as_view(), name='gallery'),
)
```

and the original views:

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView
from store.models import Category, Brand, Product

def get_brands(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q')
    if q is not None:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug__iexact=q)
        try:
            brands = category.brands.all()
        except:
            brands = []

        template = 'infobox.html'
        data = {
            'category': category,
            'brands': brands,
        }
        return render( request, template, data )



class GalleryView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'product_list'
    template_name = 'store/gallery.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug__iexact=self.args[0])
        try:
            brand = Brand.objects.get(slug__iexact = self.args[1])
            self.brand_name = brand.name
        except:
            #no brand is specified, show products with no brand
            if self.category.category_products.filter(brand__isnull=True):
                #if there are products with no brand, return those
                return self.category.category_products.filter(brand__isnull=True)
            else:
                #if all products have a brand, return the products of the first brand
                all = self.category.brands.all()
                if all:
                    brand = all[0]
                    self.brand_name = brand.name
                    return brand.brand_products.all()
                else:
                    raise Http404
        else:
            #brand is specified, show its products
            return Product.objects.filter(category=self.category, brand=brand)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(GalleryView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        category = self.category
        category_brands = self.category.brands.all()
        context['category_list'] = Category.objects.all()
        context['category'] = category
        context['crumb'] = category.name
        context['category_brands'] = category_brands
        try:
            context['brand'] = self.brand_name
        except:
            context['brand'] = None

        return context
```

Now, my custom admin app was working fine on my local dev environment, but when I added the new urls and views to prod, **Django doesn't seem to match any of the new urls**. The original views and urls still work, but none of the new urls get matched and I just keep getting a 404 Not Found error.

The updated urlconf:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


from store import views


admin_urls = patterns ('',
    url(r'^$', login_required(views.AdminIndexView.as_view()), name='admin_index'),
    url(r'^add/(\w+)/$', login_required(views.AdminAddView.as_view()), name='admin_add'),
)


urlpatterns = patterns ('',
    url(r'^category/$', views.get_brands, name='get_brands'),
    url(r'^(\w+)/$', views.GalleryView.as_view(), name='gallery'),
    url(r'^(\w+)/(\w+)/$', views.GalleryView.as_view(), name='gallery'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.admin_login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.admin_logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^logout/success/$', views.admin_logout_success, name='logout_success'),
    url(r'^test/', views.test, name='test'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin_urls, namespace='admin')),
    url(r'^ajax/$', views.ajax_request, name='ajax_request'),
)
```

Note that not even the simple '/store/test/' url does not get matched. I'm not really sure why Django isn't matching my urls, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't suppose you forgot to reload the prod server?

Comment: No, I didn't. If only the solution was that simple :I

Comment: Try commenting one line at a time and reloading.  You will prob find that something silly has been missed in a regex.  Also, I notice you changed admin to a manual inclusion, try rolling that part back (or just commenting admin out alltogether).

Comment: I tried out your suggestion, and it seems the urlconf for the administration index was the guilty party. Nothing wrong with the regex itself, though (r'^$'), but when I removed the login_required decorator it started working again. Hmm

Comment: Doesn't admin require login without the decorator? Are your views not being flagged without manually adding it?

Comment: I'm not using the Django admin, I'm constructing my own admin feature. Anyway I couldn't really understand what was going on so I decided to create the custom administration feature in a separate app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what was happening since all of my templates linked to other pages using the {% url %} tag, but I think the reason my urls were getting muddled up was because I was using the r'^(\w+)/$' regex, so it was matching any word. I simply moved the urlconfs with the (\w+) rule to the bottom of urls.py, and refactored them to be a little more specific and they were gold again.

The updated urlconf:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


from store import views


admin_urls = patterns ('',
)


urlpatterns = patterns ('',
    url(r'^category/$', views.get_brands, name='get_brands'),
    url(r'^(\w+)/$', views.GalleryView.as_view(), name='gallery'),
    url(r'^(\w+)/(\w+)/$', views.GalleryView.as_view(), name='gallery'),

    url(r'^login/$', views.admin_login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.admin_logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^logout/success/$', views.admin_logout_success, name='logout_success'),

    url(r'^ajax/$', views.ajax_request, name='ajax_request'),
    url(r'^administration/$', login_required(views.AdminIndexView.as_view()), name='admin_index'),
    url(r'^administration/add/(\w+)/$', login_required(views.AdminAddView.as_view()), name='admin_add'),
)
```

Comment: Would you like an answer explaining what's happening here?

Comment: sure, it'll help me avoid any further problems in my development :D

Comment: I thought I understood this, but not so sure anymore. Can you test out something for me? redo the urlconf like before and add this line to settings.py: `LOGIN_URL = '/store/login/'`

Comment: Actually, I already did have that in my settings.py. Sorry, I wasn't clear about that in the question.

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Comment: So you're saying that the reason the views that required login weren't being found is because the login urlconf wasn't defined yet? I was logged in the whole time I was testing, though, so shouldn't it have gone straight to the view?

Comment: If you were logged in then yeah. Admin also uses `admin:login` in it's templates so I'm actually not that sure my suggestion is correct. weird case indeed

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comments, removing login_required fixes the problem. Here's what the django docs have to say about the decorator:

> login_required() does the following:
>
> 1. If the user isn’t logged in, redirect to settings.LOGIN_URL, passing the current absolute path in the query string. Example:
>      /accounts/login/?next=/polls/3/.
> 2. If the user is logged in, execute the view normally
>
> [...] Note that if you don't specify the login_url parameter, you'll
>   need to map the appropriate Django view to settings.LOGIN_URL.

In other words, it goes to a default url you can override in settings.LOGIN_URL.

Now here's what I think happened - I think you defined your own login here:

```
url(r'^login/$', views.admin_login, name='login'),
```

And because the login_required in the new urls pointed at the default url, which doesn't exist it returned 404. However, when you configured the login_required views *after* your other urls:

```
url(r'^login/$', views.admin_login, name='login'),
...
url(r'^administration/$', login_required(views.AdminIndexView.as_view()), name='admin_index'),
url(r'^administration/add/(\w+)/$', login_required(views.AdminAddView.as_view()), name='admin_add'),
```

it worked. Why is that? You didn't overrid LOGIN_URL here right? But you sort of did - because at this point, you redefined the namespace 'login' to point to your own view. Now this isn't mentioned anywhere in the docs, but it makes sense, and looking at the default admin templates you can see this is the namespace being used.

Does that make sense to you?